# PHP 7 shutting down php -S localhost:8000

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

I am having a problem when I run the command I get this error. 
Failed to listen on `localhost:8000`

> reason: Cannot assign requested address

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there is already another process listening on this port.

Comment: i have check using sudo netstat -plnt but  port  8000 is  not in use

Comment: Can you use another port?

Comment: i have try to use several ports but not working